# Extract objects from nested json with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a nested json (like the one reported below) of translated labels, and I want to extract the leaves in separate json files, based on the languages key (`it`, `en`, etc).

I don't know at "compile time" the depth and the schema of the json, because there are a lot of files similiar to the big nested one, but I know that I always have the following structure: key `path/to/en/label` and value `content`.

I tried using Pandas with the [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) function to flatten my json, and works great, but afterwards I had trouble rebuilding the json schema, e.g. with the following json I get a 1x12 DataFrame, but I want a resulting DataFrame with shape 4x3, where 4 are the different labels (index) and 3 are the different languages (columns).

```py
def fix_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    assert df.shape[0] == 1
    columns = df.columns
    columns_last_piece = [s.split("/")[-1] for s in columns]
    fixed_columns = [s.split(".")[1] for s in columns_last_piece]
    index = [".".join(elem.split(".")[2:]) for elem in columns_last_piece]
    return pd.DataFrame(df.values, index=index, columns=fixed_columns)


def main():
    path = pathlib.Path(os.getenv("FIXTURE_FLATTEN_PATH"))
    assert path.exists()

    json_dict = json.load(open(path, encoding="utf-8"))
    flattened_json = pd.json_normalize(json_dict)
    flattened_json_fixed = fix_df(flattened_json)
    # do something with flattened_json_fixed
```

Example of `my_labels.json`:

```json
{
  "dynamicData": {
    "bff_scoring": {
      "subCollection": {
        "dynamicData/bff_scoring/translations": {
          "it": {
            "area_title.people": "PERSONE",
            "area_title.planet": "PIANETA",
            "area_title.prosperity": "PROSPERITÀ",
            "area_title.principle-gov": "PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE"
          },
          "en": {
            "area_title.people": "PEOPLE",
            "area_title.planet": "PLANET",
            "area_title.prosperity": "PROSPERITY",
            "area_title.principle-gov": "PRINCIPLE OF GOVERNANCE"
          },
          "fr":{
            "area_title.people": "PERSONNES",
            "area_title.planet": "PLANÈTE",
            "area_title.prosperity": "PROSPERITÉ",
            "area_title.principle-gov": "PRINCIPES DE GOUVERNANCE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of `my_labels_it.json`:

```json
{
  "area_title.people": "PERSONE",
  "area_title.planet": "PIANETA",
  "area_title.prosperity": "PROSPERITÀ",
  "area_title.principle-gov": "PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE"
}
```

Comment: are the path names known? I don't think you need pandas here; never mind json_normalize. Just looping through the dict, perhaps recursively should be better.

Comment: No, I don't know them. I think you're right, but I thought that a flat DataFrame could be easily reshaped to match my desired output

Comment: do you know how many sub dir you have?  Always 4 down, `1/2/3/4/it/area_title.pelple`?

Comment: No, unfortunately, but I know that I always have `<codeLanguage>/label` as leaf

Comment: hmm, that seems no easy way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem.

First, I need to use the `melt` function.

```py
>>> df = flattened_json.melt()
>>> df
                                             variable                     value
0   dynamicData.bff_scoring.subCollection.dynamicD...                   PERSONE
1   dynamicData.bff_scoring.subCollection.dynamicD...                   PIANETA
2   dynamicData.bff_scoring.subCollection.dynamicD...                PROSPERITÀ
3   dynamicData.bff_scoring.subCollection.dynamicD...    PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE
...
```

From here, I can extract the fields I'm interested with a regular expression. I tried using `.str.extractall` and `explode`, but I was greeted with an exception, so I relied to use `.str.extract` two times.

```py
>>> df2 = df.assign(language=df.variable.str.extract(r".*\.([a-z]{2})\.[\w\.-]+$"), label=df.variable.str.extract(r"(?<=\.[a-z]{2}\.)([\w\.-]+)$")).drop(columns="variable")
>>> df2
                       value language                     label
0                    PERSONE       it         area_title.people
1                    PIANETA       it         area_title.planet
2                 PROSPERITÀ       it     area_title.prosperity
3     PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE       it  area_title.principle-gov
...
```

And then, with a `pivot`, I can have the dataframe with the desired schema.

```py
>>> df3 = df2.pivot(index="label", columns="language", values="value")
>>> df3
language                                       en  ...                      it
label                                              ...                        
area_title.people                          PEOPLE  ...                 PERSONE
area_title.planet                          PLANET  ...                 PIANETA
area_title.principle-gov  PRINCIPLE OF GOVERNANCE  ...  PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE
area_title.prosperity                  PROSPERITY  ...              PROSPERITÀ
```

From this dataframe is very simple to obtain the expected json.

```py
>>> df3["it"].to_json(force_ascii=False)
'{"area_title.people":"PERSONE","area_title.planet":"PIANETA","area_title.principle-gov":"PRINCIPI DI GOVERNANCE","area_title.prosperity":"PROSPERITÀ"}'
```